# DRF GET serializer: get parent id in a nested relationship (extra fields in a nested manytomany relationship with through model)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Having the following models

```py
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    vehicles =  models.ManyToManyField(Vehicle,through="VehicleHousing", through_fields=('house', 'vehicle'),)
    habitants =  models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,through="UserHousing", through_fields=('house', 'habitant'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12,default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    houses =  models.ManyToManyField(House,through="UserHousing", through_fields=('habitant', 'house'),)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class UserHousing(models.Model):
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    habitant = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['habitant', 'house']]
```

The user model is a custom user model replacing the base one, replacing also `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the `settings.py` module.

I got the following serializers to get the data to the view:

```py
class UserBasicInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    admin = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_admin')

    def get_admin(self, obj):
        admin = UserHousing.objects.get(habitant=obj).isAdmin
        return admin
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'admin']
        
class VehicleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['id','license_plate','brand','model','hexcolor']

class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    habitants = UserBasicInfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    vehicles = VehicleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ['id','name', 'address', 'vehicles', 'habitants']

class UserFullInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    houses = HouseSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'houses']
```

Ending up with the following response from the request in the view:

```py
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "mail@mail.com",
        "first_name": "name",
        "last_name": "lastname",
        "phone_number": null,
        "houses": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "housename",
                "address": "adress",
                "vehicles": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "license_plate": "2300WTS",
                        "brand": "Mercedes",
                        "model": "B",
                        "hexcolor": "#F1F1F1"
                    }
                ],
                "habitants": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "email": "mail@mail.com",
                        "first_name": "name",
                        "last_name": "lastname",
                        "phone_number": null,
                        "admin": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "email": "2ndmail@mail.com",
                        "first_name": "secondname",
                        "last_name": "secondlastname",
                        "phone_number": null,
                        "admin": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

After all that is explained, here is my problem, as you can see I'm using a `.get()` in `UserBasicInfoSerializer` to get if the user is admin or not. It works nicely when the user has only 1 house linked to him but once you link another house to the user it will result in a [MultipleObjectsReturned](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) error.

As the user is only allowed to be listed one time in one house, having the id of the parent house would solve my problem but, I don't know how to get it into the `UserBasicInfoSerializer`, if I could I would do the following and my problem would be solved:

```py
admin = UserHousing.objects.get(habitant=obj, house=house.id).isAdmin
```

How can I get parent information into this nested Serializer?

Alternatives would also come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should solve your issue:

```
class UserBasicInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    admin = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_admin')

    def get_admin(self, obj):
        house = self.context["house"]
        admin = UserHousing.objects.get(habitant=obj, house=house).isAdmin
        return admin
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'admin']

class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    habitants = SerializerMethodField()
    vehicles = VehicleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ['id','name', 'address', 'vehicles', 'habitants']

    def get_habitants(self, house):
        context = getattr(self, "context", None) or {}
        context["house"] = house
        return UserBasicInfoSerializer(house.habitants.all(), many=True, context=context).data
```

Comment: I get TypeError: Object of type ListSerializer is not JSON serializable

Comment: To fix the type error, in the response you need `.data` at the end or otherwise you returning the serializer and not the data. But it works that way.

Comment: You're right, I forgot